# How to partial import in stylus

Tags: inheritance, import, extend, partial, stylus

How to implement partial import (extend, include, inheritance) in stylus?
For instance I have two files:

- foo.styl `body {color:orange} a {color: blue}`
- bar.styl

Within file `bar.styl` I want place `body {color:orange}` from `foo.styl` but do not want `a {color: blue}`
How can it be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing (yet) in Stylus. It could be possible using this trick:

```
$foo
  @import 'test2'

body
  @extends $foo body
```

But Stylus had a bug: https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/issues/1687 — preventing this from rendering properly. This bug was fixed in Stylus 0.49.0, so if you're using this or later version, everything should be fine.

As the problem had happen only when the selector where you'd been trying to use `@extends` matched the nested selector, you could somewhat trick Stylus to think the selector is not the same. The most simple and easy way is to write it this way:

```
$foo
  @import 'test2'

* > body
  @extends $foo body
```

This would make Stylus not think of those selectors as equal and would output `* > body` properly. While the star selector is often harmful, in that case it is not: as it is placed on the left and have a child combinator, it won't cause performance problems when the selector matching happens, and as star selector don't have any specificity on it, it won't interfere with the specificity of the given rule.

However, if you could wait a bit, we could try to fix this bug in Stylus, so you could use the fix code from the start of this answer in one of the next releases.

Comment: Great thanks a lot! I will try workaround now, and will wait new release.

Comment: Sorry no. It does not work. It worked because comment in the end :( I realized that just right now.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgBEw  
But when I delete it, it stopped working.
>>  > 7|   @extends $foo .{prefix} #social
>> 
>> Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Comment: I use `grunt-contrib-stylus` does it make sense?

Comment: Interpolation is not working perfectly at `@extends`, so it is better to do all the stuff inside the interpolation, like this: `@extends {'$foo .%s #social' % prefix}`. Also, the fix for the bug mentioned in the answer is already in Stylus 0.49.0, so if you'd update Stylus to this version, it should work without the workaround.

Comment: Ok, but it does not described in the [site](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/) thus I cannot know some additional stuff, for instance — how copy `color` from `a {color:red; padding: 50px;}`. Just interested in partial inheritance. Thanks a lot!